# I don't understand this process in solving the cubic

Tags: polynomials, cubics

My previous question was about the cubic. Now, the following confuses me

> Q. Use $\cos{3 \theta}=4 \cos^3{\theta}-3 \cos{\theta}$ to solve the cubic $t^3+pt+q=0$ for $p,q$ real when $27q^2+4p^3<0$

Here goes the solution

> Since $27q^2+4p^3<0$ the cubic has three real roots. For this to be true, $-(27q^2+4p^3)>0$ and therefore $p<0$. If we let $t=u \cos{\theta}$ then our equation becomes
>
> $$0=u^3 \cos^3{\theta}+pu\cos{\theta}+q \Rightarrow 0= 4 \cos^3{\theta}+\frac{4p}{u^2}\cos{\theta}+\frac{4q}{u^3}$$
>
> since $p<0$,

Here comes what I don't get why

> "we may solve $u=\sqrt{\frac{-4p}{3}}$ ($\leftarrow$ where did this come from?) for real $u$"

Reverse engineering tells me this is true if $\frac{4p}{u^2}+3=0$ is true. But what assures this? I thought of comparing coefficients.

So, $0=4 \cos^3{\theta}+\frac{4p}{u^2}\cos{\theta}+\frac{4q}{u^3}$ and $\cos{3 \theta}=4 \cos^3{\theta}-3 \cos{\theta}$ this gives, by rearranging since they both have $4\cos^3{\theta}$,

$$\cos{3 \theta}+3 \cos{\theta}=-\frac{4p}{u^2}\cos{\theta}-\frac{4q}{u^3}$$

Well, comparing coefficients doesn't seem right here because $\cos{3 \theta}$ gets in the way. Namely, sure I can collect the terms and get $(3+\frac{4p}{u^2})\cos{\theta}$ but nothing, nothing at all, assures me that this coefficient must be zero.

So I don't know where the solution made that leap in logic. It's really not apparent or obvious to me. Why is $3+\frac{4p}{u^2}=0$?

Comment: You don't derive $u$ from the expression. In fact, you choose $u = \sqrt{(-4p/3)}$.  To see why that is useful, substitute $u$ into $$4 \cos^3 \theta + \frac{4p}{u^2} \cos \theta + \frac{4q}{u^3}$$
What do you conclude?

Comment: Wait, so you are saying that there's no derivation and it's just some assumption made purely for convenience? It comes not from logical reasoning, but just as how said "okay, let's say $t= u \cos{\theta}$ because that'll come in handy later on. Just a good guess."?

Comment: Yes, the proof starts with choosing $t = u \cos \theta$. Here, no assumptions about $u$ are yet made. The reason this substitution works is that you will be able to choose $u$ in a clever way such that you can solve the equation. Try the substitution, you'll see that it will lead to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it in a slightly different way: set $t=u\cos\theta$; then the equation becomes
$$
u^3\cos^3\theta+pu\cos\theta+q=0
$$
and we are still free to choose whatever value of $u\ne0$ we want. Dividing by $u^3$ and multiplying by $4$ we have
$$
4\cos^3\theta+\frac{4p}{u^2}\cos\theta+\frac{4q}{u^3}=0
$$
and we can choose
$$
\frac{4p}{u^2}=-3
$$
that is, $u=\sqrt{-4p/3}$, and the equation becomes
$$
4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta=-\frac{4q}{u^3}
$$
or
$$
\cos3\theta=-\frac{4q}{u^3}
$$
Note that
$$
\left(-\frac{4q}{u^3}\right)^2=\frac{16q^2}{u^6}=\frac{16q^2}{(-4p/3)^3}
\le1
$$
because of the hypothesis that the discriminant is negative. So the equation in the unknown $\theta$ has solutions.