# Cubic's Irreducible case.

Tags: polynomials, cubics

I know how to solve a cubic equation using Cardano's method, but some equation when solved through Cardano's method give complex numbers under a cube root sign.
For Example:
$x^3-15x=4$.
I want to know how are these types of equations solved.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis#Non-algebraic_solution_in_terms_of_real_quantities.

Comment: Related: [I don't understand this process in solving the cubic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732311/i-dont-understand-this-process-in-solving-the-cubic)

Comment: That is exactly the reason for the appearance of complex numbers in history. 
If a third degree polynomial has a negative discriminant, it has a unique real root, given by the sum of two conjugated complex numbers in Cardano's formula. But in our case,
$$ p(x)=x^3-15x-4 $$
has a positive discriminant, hence three real roots.